# web-mode not installing?

Tags: package, web-mode

The short version of my question is **how do I install web-mode?**

Here's what I've tried so far:

I'm trying to install `web-mode`, so I typed in `M-x package-install`, followed by `web-mode`.  At this point it fails with the message:

```
https://stable.melpa.org/packages/web-mode-15.el: Not found
```

Going to the [MELPA page for web-mode](http://stable.melpa.org/#/web-mode) I see a large '16' on it (as of now - August 6, 2018).

My guess is that my emacs is asking for version 15, and it doesn't exist because the current version is 16, but setting [`package-load-list`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Package-Installation.html) to be "16" for `web-mode` only produces an error.

I'm sure there's something goofy with my setup / something I'm missing, but could anyone **help me to install web-mode?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think what's happening is that the list of packages Emacs knows about is out of date; your system thinks web-mode 15 is the latest, but web-mode 16 has been published to the package repository. Your Emacs stores the list of packages it knows about in the variable `package-archive-contents`, if you want to check that. But looking at that variable isn't necessary to fix it.

To update web-mode, run `M-x list-packages`. Emacs will fetch the list of packages available for install, and present that list in a buffer.

You can then go in that buffer to `web-mode`, press `i` to mark that package for installation, then press `x` to execute the instructions, and install `web-mode`.